# create a connector to a smarthost that requires authentication on exchange online

Tags: exchangeonline

Can you create a connector to a smarthost that requires authentication on Exchange Online? I looked at the documentation for New-OutboundConnector, and I don't see a place to set the authentication credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don’t know this setting, but we can use TLS :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-for-secure-mail-flow-with-a-partner

May I know the function of this smart host? for filtering spam and malware or archiving or auditing?

You could refer to the following article:
Manage mail flow using a third-party cloud service with Exchange Online
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/manage-mail-flow-using-third-party-cloud